# Math journals for Calculus students

Tags: calculus, soft-question

I have a student in my Calculus 2 class who might be interested in majoring in Mathematics.  He asked be if there were any math journals suited for a less experienced readers. There have been questions like this asked before on Stack Exchange, but everything that has been recommended either costs money or is still beyond his current scope.  Does anyone know at least good papers a calculus student could enjoy? Are there any recommendations for me to point him in the right direction?

Comment: Wouldn't reading lecture notes about surprising ideas like "every vector space has a basis" satisfy the implied originality request?

Comment: I think for know, let the student work on various problems and a lot of them. For the most part, reading subtracts time from actually learning. In my experience I read more than I need to, to be able to tackle a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that would be nice.  I can point him to Paul Halmos' book, "Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces"

Comment: I can understand Faraad, it's sometimes wise to stay where you are and focus on getting good at that for the moment. But I can also understand being an eager student curious about what else is out there

Comment: Once you have some journals in mind, with regard to the cost: if there is a nearby university, your student might try to find a librarian there who can look for ways he can get access to the desired journals.

Comment: Yeah I forgot about MathSciNet

Answer (score 4):

You might try [The College Mathematics Journal](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal) and [Crux Mathematicorum](https://cms.math.ca/crux/).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the college mathematics journal by the MAA.

Answer (score 2):

I have been reading [Math and CS Research](https://mathcsr.org) recently and it is a great resource for Calculus students. It is free and most of its articles do not go beyond Calculus concepts but its articles still manage to make significant and interest results.

Comment: You're 5 years late but after skimming what you suggested, I already like it. Thanks :-)