# Please suggest a Journal to submit my paper on elementary calculus

Tags: calculus

I was wondering for an appropriate journal which publishes articles on elementary (but rigorous) calculus, possibly of undergraduate level. I want to submit an article on Calculus (19 pages). I know The College Mathematics Journal and Mathematics Magazine publish articles on Calculus ([Math journals for Calculus students](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708296/math-journals-for-calculus-students)) but they limit the article length to at most 8 pages. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the content? Is it pedagogy? Some new calculation? (This is also probably better suited for academia.se)

Comment: Content is some new calculations in elementary calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what do you mean with paper in "elementary calculus" but I think that The American Mathematical Monthly publish papers about elementary mathematics.

http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly

In any case, did you put it on arXiv?

https://arxiv.org

Comment: O yes that I know, however, I believe that American Mathematical monthly demand very high standards of Engli sh writing skills, and I am moderate in that. Also, I have not put the article on arXiv. Will it be good to do so?

Comment: I don't know it depends on what you wrote... I suggest to speak with someone in you department that can evaluate your work and advice you about what to do with your paper.

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much.

Comment: @AntonioAlfieri I have a question myself, if I put results on arxiv will that effect the ability of the results being published in a peer reviewed scholarly article?

Comment: No, at all. There are papers on the arxiv that were published on the Annals.